# Import ODATA via python requests

Tags: python, connection, export, odata

I am lost
I want to load OData via python from Every ANgle. But I am not getting the whole data set but just top 3000 rows. Dont you know how to solve it?
I think there is something with URL I am using. My code:

```
import pyodata
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np
import pymssql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

r=requests.get('https://everyangle.fabory.com/odata/R3P_300/odata/Stock_MS30_LABST_LBKUM_L2_6394_30806/?$format=data)
print(r.status_code)
```

Once I loaded it all to PowerBi I see this:
[image]

Comment: Do you know if the service implements server-side paging such that a maximum of 3000 records can be returned at a go? Is there a nextLink in the response to enable you fetch the next batch of records?

Comment: Hi John, please is there a way how I cant find it out? I havent seen anything like that in the xml export of those 3000.

Comment: The response from the service would be JSON. If server-side paging is implemented, I'd expect you to find an `@odata.nextLink` property, in addition to the `value` property

Answer (score 0):

The server is probably using pagination. Here is [how to use pagination with pyodata](https://pyodata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/querying.html#experimental-query-server-side-paginations-using-the-next-field).

```py
employees = northwind.entity_sets.Employees.get_entities().select('EmployeeID,LastName').execute()
while True:
    for employee in employees:
        print(employee.EmployeeID, employee.LastName)

    # Stop if server has no more entities left
    if employees.next_url is None:
        break

    # We got a partial answer - continue with next page
    employees = northwind.entity_sets.Employees.get_entities().next_url(employees.next_url).execute()
```